# JQuery How do I add an id to the parent div of an iframe with the value of iframes id + "whatever"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this html

```
<div id="cont">
<div id="videowrapper" class="fitmein">
<div id="vimeoposition" style="display: block;">
<div class="fluid-width-video-wrapper" style="padding-top: 56.25%;">
<iframe id="player1" class="vimeo" src="http://player.vimeo.com/blablabla">
</div>
<div class="fluid-width-video-wrapper" style="padding-top: 56.25%;">
<iframe id="player2" class="vimeo" src="http://player.vimeo.com/blablabla">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to add now an id to each div with the fluid-width-video-wrapper class.
The new ids value should begin with "fluid" followed by the value of iframe id nested in that div.

So the result would look like (of course without the **s, just for highlighting):

```
<div **id="fluidplayer1"** class="fluid-width-video-wrapper" style="padding-top: 56.25%;">
<iframe **id="player1"** class="vimeo" src="http://player.vimeo.com/blablabla">
</div>
<div **id="fluidplayer2"** class="fluid-width-video-wrapper" style="padding-top: 56.25%;">
<iframe **id="player2"** class="vimeo" src="http://player.vimeo.com/blablabla">
</div>
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Thank you ALL very very much for your great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the

> .each

```
$('.fluid-width-video-wrapper').each(function() {
   var player = $(this).children().attr("id");
   $(this).attr('id', 'fluid'+player);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {

      $(".fluid-width-video-wrapper").each(function(index) {
          $(this).attr("id","fluidplayer" + index);
      });

  });
</script>
```

That should do it, you could use a .next() to get the `id` of the next element if you needed it to be 100% dynamic.

See:
Each - http://api.jquery.com/each/
Attr - http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Edit

---

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(function() { 

      $(".fluid-width-video-wrapper").each(function(index) { 
          $(this).attr("id","fluid" + $(this).children("iframe").attr("id")); 
      }); 

  }); 
</script>
```

Should be the dynamic version.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".classname").each(function(count){$(this).attr("id","new-id"+count)});
```

Answer (score 0):

some thing like this  . [JSFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/mK5ED/2/)

```
$('iframe').each(function(){
  var divObj = $(this).parent('div').attr('id',$(this).attr('id') + 1)
      alert($(divObj).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find out each div with the fluid-width-video-wrapper class by using .each() method.  Then you find the children of that div, that is your iframe and get the id of the iframe.  Then append 'fluid ' to the id of the iframe and make it id of your div.
Here is the code.

```
$('.fluid-width-video-wrapper').each(function() {
    var divID = $(this).children('iframe').attr("id");
    $(this).attr('id', 'fluid' + divID);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not make use of child selectors and parent()?

```
$('.fluid-width-video-wrapper > iframe').each(function(){
  $(this).parent().attr("id", "fluid" + $(this).attr('id')); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var frame = document.getElementById("frame1");
        var win =  frame.contentWindow;
        win.showMessage("Hello from Main Page in iFrame");
    };    
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?